# How to get url for android from asp.net mvc controller that I can call this webservice for signin?

Tags: c#, android, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want this code in `json` response and want request `url` that I can easily call it in android. I want to just call this webservice in android.

```
public JsonResult LoginPatient(Patients lc)

    {
        string mainconn = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dhc"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select PatientEmail,PatientPassword from [dbo].[Patients] where PatientEmail=@PatientEmail and PatientPassword=@PatientPassword";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientEmail", lc.PatientEmail);
      sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientPassword",lc.PatientPassword);
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
          Session["PatientEmail"] = lc.PatientEmail.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Patient Login Details Failed ";

        }
        sqlconn.Close();
        return Json (View());
    }
```

I want to call this in `android` for sign in patients. So I want an `URL`. How to get it?

Comment: Assuming this is in a controller, then your url is your server name + the route to this method. By default `{server}:{port}/{controller}/LoginPatient`

Comment: But how to get json response?

Comment: What do you mean by android? What language are you using to call it?